# Eloquent One to Many Relationship in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am trying to get data of country name so,

I have two model

1)users model

users:

```
class Users extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = ['fname','lname','email','password','address','state','city'];


    public function address1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Addresses');
    }
}
```

2)addresses model

addresses:

```
class addresses extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','country'];

    public function user()
    {
        return  $this->belongTo('App\users');
    }
}
```

now I am getting output - it is an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'addresses.users_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `addresses`
>   where `addresses`.`users_id` = 5 and `addresses`.`users_id` is not
>   null and `addresses`.`id` = 2 limit 1) (View:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/demo/resources/views/profiles.blade.php)

please, solve my problem.

Comment: So, have you read that error message? It tells you very clearly what the problem is....

Comment: not getting data from database

Comment: What do you mean by that? Have you read the error message?

Comment: Follow naming conventions! Laravel tries to guess the foreign key from the name of the associated Model, and since your model is `Users` and not `User`, it's trying to find `users_id` instead of the correct `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, error tells very clear what is the problem - you don't have `users_id` column in your `addresses` table.

You haven't showed how exactly you try to use those relationships, but I believe the problem is here:

```
 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongTo('App\users');
 }
```

As you use model names that don't follow Laravel convention, you should pass foreign key column name, for example:

```
 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongTo('App\users', 'user_id');
 }
```

Here `user_id` is just an example. I don't know what is the real column name in your table that defines relationship to user.

However I would strongly recomment you using Laravel and PHP conventions:

1. class should start with capital letter, so instead of `addresses` it should be rather `Addresses` (remember to have file name with exact same case so for example Addresses.php`
2. Models should be singular nouns, so instead of Addresses or Users it should be rather Address or User (again make sure in case you decide to change it you change also filename)

Comment: Thank you very much.. it is code working... thnaks again :)